# Docker: editing my.cnf in when building the image

Tags: docker

I am fairly new with docker. I wonder if there is a way how to "hardcode" my.cnf settings for docker image, instead of editing the docker container.

I need to add these two lines into my.cnf for my app to work:

```
[client]
protocol=tcp
```

Currently, I build the image run the container & edit it manually by going into /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy at build time

```
FROM mysql
COPY my_custom.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

or another way is to change the config file and mount the config file at run time so you will not need to rebuild or maintain a custom image.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

**Using a custom MySQL configuration file**

> The default configuration for MySQL can be found in
>   `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, which may !includedir additional directories such
>   as `/etc/mysql/conf.d` or `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`. Please inspect
>   the relevant files and directories within the mysql image itself for
>   more details.
>
> If `/my/custom/config-file.cnf` is the path and name of your custom
>   configuration file, you can start your mysql container like this (note
>   that only the directory path of the custom config file is used in this
>   command):

```
 $ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d
 mysql:tag
```

> This will start a new container some-mysql where the
>   MySQL instance uses the combined startup settings from
>   `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf`, with
>   settings from the latter taking precedence.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

**update:**

For TCP only, you do not need to mount your config, just run with `--protocol` flag.

```
docker run --rm -it -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=test mysql:5.6.24 --protocol=TCP
```

Comment: Hi Adiii. The best way for me is to change/edit/copy my.cnf at a build time. Should I include my_custom.cnf in a folder where Dockerfile is? I have tried that but the my.cnf inside docker is not changed when I run the image. Thanks.

Comment: try with `COPY config/ /etc/mysql/` and also download offical and do changes https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/6659750146b7a6b91a96c786729b4d482cf49fe6/8.0/config

Comment: Hi. It works now. It was my stupid mistake of putting "COPY my_custom.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf" before "RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server" and "RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client". Thanks for your help!